# What is the purpose of using a session id when csrf protection is already implemented?

Tags: session, cookies, token, csrf, sessionid

I know that to protect web applications from Cross Site Request Forgery, the only secure method is implementing a CSRF token. My question is, isn't it possible to use the CSRF token to track sessions also? Why should we implement a different session id to track the sessions?

Answer (score 5):

A CSRF token is a value that must be generated randomly and associated to a session (a user) in **EVERY** GET that shows a form to prevent false POST. This false POST comes from the user browser too so, to authenticate the POST, you need a session with the token stored in server memory to compare if the token that comes with the POST is the same that is stored in user session.

Also, web app's should need to identify users in a GET and CSRF tokens are only in POST.

Session need to be static to identify user along time and several request due to disconnected nature of HTTP. CSRF changes in every GET, it can not be used like session.

On the other hand, what should server do with your idea? Create a new session every GET request and copy all previous session data to the new session? This is crazy.

Take a look to [this pdf](http://www.cs.montana.edu/courses/csci476/topics/crosssite_attacks.pdf) at Montana State University. It helped me to understand CSRF.

Comment: "**CSRF tokens are only in POST**" wrong! I think your whole idea about csrf tokens are wrong.

Comment: Short answer: Session need to be static to identify user along time. CSRF changes in every GET so If you are repeating CSRF tokens to use them like session your are doing wrong.

Comment: In my understanding CSRF tokens can be send either in url or POST body content. For the purpose of security we use POST. But thats not the question. Can't we simply use CSRF tokens as session identifiers? Even if they are random chars, still the server knows its value for a user in a specific session rite? Can't that information be used for session identification?

Comment: But the token must be unique in every response you want to include CSRF token. This is why can not be used as session.

Comment: And how do you add a CSRF token in a query string when user do a plain GET without token? 302 and the same location header with token? 2 roundtrips just to add a CSRF tokent to query string? I do not want that in my web app. Also if you need CSRF token in GET means you need to athorize the request; that means you are designing an app in wich GET are not idempotent and this is a bad idea.

Comment: @jivaquero Yes, the token must be unique, its unique for each user and its gets compared at server side also. Still, "The token must be different for different request" criteria does not actually stop a developer from using csrf tokens as session identifiers, at least since they are verified for authentication and authorization at server side.

Comment: @jlvaquero you can send a CSRF token in a cookie to work with an ajax get. There are a lot of ways to use CSRF not only in a POST

Comment: @Anonymous Platypus but if you store session info in the server side (RAM memory, redis, etc) every time you generate a new CSRF token you are creating a new Session ID. So, you have to move all that info to the new session. As you generate a lot of CSRF tokens in the web app lifecicle this is not a good idea.

Comment: @nada CSRF vector attack is exploiting the session cookie that is send to the server by the browser even for a undesired POST. So, not, you should not, never ever use a cookie to store and sent CSRF token to the server because it will be sent to the server and the server will authorize the request.

Comment: @Anonymous Platypus You also has to search by hand to find token-user correspondecy in your proposition. Don't forget that session implies more than just user identification. You could, in deed, use CSRF token to identify the user if you sent tokens to the user every request form the loggin screen and so on but it is not the same as session because session implies a lot of things implemented in web app, not just user identification. Aslo implies a lot of handcrafting work if you try to bypass web app session and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the purpose of a session id other than authentication and authorization? I am not a developer, so don't know anything beyond that.

Comment: The purpose is identify the user. The implications are: Generate cryptographycaly secure ID's to avoid session forging, efficient data association and storing, session expiration in server, resources dispossing, and a lot of things of this nature.